# Multiple Screen on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, display, displayport

I'm actually on ubuntu 18.04 with a HP computer.
I have 3 screens plugged (display port) to the computer but only one is detected.

Here are some information I get following some commands I can found on some forums:
`sudo lshw -c display`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:15:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:387f0-387ef iomemory:387f0-387ef memory:91000000-91ffffff memory:387fe0000000-387fefffffff memory:387ff0000000-387ff1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:92080000-920fffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2d:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:c000(size=128) memory:b3080000-b30fffff
```

`xrandr`

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
```

Only the end of file of
`lspci -v`

```
14:0e.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:0e.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:0e.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:0f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:0f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:0f.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:0f.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:0f.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:0f.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:0f.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:10.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:10.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:10.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:10.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:10.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:10.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:10.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:11.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:11.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:11.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:11.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:1d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:1d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:1d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:1d.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E CHA Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:1e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:1e.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:1e.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:1e.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:1e.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:1e.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

14:1e.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

15:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e04 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8675
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 212, NUMA node 0
    Memory at 91000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 387fe0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at 387ff0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 92080000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

15:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f7 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8675
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 210, NUMA node 0
    Memory at 92000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

15:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1ad6 (rev a1) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8675
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35, NUMA node 0
    Memory at 387ff2000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Memory at 387ff2040000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

15:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1ad7 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8675
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255, NUMA node 0
    Memory at 92004000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port A (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Physical Slot: 7
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28, NUMA node 0
    Bus: primary=20, secondary=21, subordinate=21, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

20:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port B (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Physical Slot: 5
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29, NUMA node 0
    Bus: primary=20, secondary=22, subordinate=22, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

20:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port C (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Physical Slot: 8
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30, NUMA node 0
    Bus: primary=20, secondary=23, subordinate=23, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

20:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port D (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Physical Slot: 8-1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31, NUMA node 0
    Bus: primary=20, secondary=24, subordinate=24, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: 92800000-928fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

20:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2034 (rev 04)
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers (rev 04)
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Device 2036 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [IO(X)-APIC])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, NUMA node 0
    Memory at 92900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2066 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skx_uncore

20:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2066 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skx_uncore

20:0a.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2040 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0a.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2041 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0a.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2042 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skx_uncore

20:0a.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2043 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0a.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2044 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0a.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2045 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0a.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2046 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skx_uncore

20:0a.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2047 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2048 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0b.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2049 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0b.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 204a (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skx_uncore

20:0b.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 204b (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2040 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0c.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2041 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0c.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2042 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skx_uncore

20:0c.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2043 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0c.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2044 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0c.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2045 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0c.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2046 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skx_uncore

20:0c.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2047 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2048 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2049 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

20:0d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 204a (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skx_uncore

20:0d.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 204b (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

24:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981 (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a801
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40, NUMA node 0
    Memory at 92800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme

2c:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port A (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Physical Slot: 2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32, NUMA node 0
    Bus: primary=2c, secondary=2d, subordinate=2d, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000c000-0000cfff
    Memory behind bridge: a0000000-b30fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 000038fffff00000-000038ffffffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

2c:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2034 (rev 04)
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

2c:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers (rev 04)
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

2c:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Device 2036 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [IO(X)-APIC])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, NUMA node 0
    Memory at b3100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

2c:0e.0 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Device 2058 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skx_uncore

2c:0e.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2059 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

2c:0f.0 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Device 2058 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skx_uncore

2c:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2059 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

2c:10.0 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Device 2058 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skx_uncore

2c:10.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 2059 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

2c:12.0 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

2c:12.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Kernel driver in use: skx_uncore

2c:12.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Kernel driver in use: skx_uncore

2c:12.4 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

2c:12.5 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M3KTI Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Kernel driver in use: skx_uncore

2c:15.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

2c:16.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

2c:16.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

2c:17.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

2d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1e04 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8675
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 213, NUMA node 0
    Memory at b2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at c000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at b3080000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

2d:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f7 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8675
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 211, NUMA node 0
    Memory at b3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

2d:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1ad6 (rev a1) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8675
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37, NUMA node 0
    Memory at 38fffff00000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Memory at 38fffff40000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

2d:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1ad7 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8675
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255, NUMA node 0
    Memory at b3004000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

When I go to the display menu I get [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD9mP.png)

Any help is more than welcome :)

Comment: Have you installed the NVIDIA proprietary drivers? If yes, what is the output of `prime-select query`?

Comment: @user3140225 : the output is 
```uery
nvidia```
Is that helping ?
Thanks for your answer